# Disappearing column filter value

Tags: powerquery

In Power Query Editor, I have a table I want to filter on a specific column. When I click on the arrow on the column header, it first gives me following items:

[image]

When I click "Load More", the first entry "100R1" is not available anymore? I also know there should be other values (like "500", but those are also not shown)...

[image]

This behaviour starts only after I do a NestedJoin like so:

```
  = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Number"},Parts,{"Parts"},"Parts",JoinKind.Inner)
```

So, the column that I join on is `Number`, the column I want to filter on is `Type` ...
When I try to filter `Type` on the `Source` table, it behavious correctly...

How is this possible?

PS: If I adjust the filter manually from:

```
Table.SelectRows(JoinedTable, each ([Type] = "100R2" or [Type] = "400R1" or [Type] = "400R2"))
```

to

```
Table.SelectRows(JoinedTable, each ([Type] = "100R2" or [Type] = "400R1" or [Type] = "400R2" or [Type] = "100R1"))
```

it effectively keeps instances of "100R1" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I've faced situation, when filters in PQ are lied to me. The problem was solved by clearing cash.

Comment: I was too fast to judge. After clearing the cache, I have closed Power BI and restarted it, and the filters were working normal again. Thanks!